# js+php+bootstrap

Tags: javascript, php, bootstrap

такая связка: передаю в js переменную, js передаёт в php, получает данные в alert... в ответе может быть несколько строк...
пытался отформатировать через \n, но хром не даёт в таком случае выделять строки в окне alert и копировать, хотя FF пофиг, он даёт...
гуглил, таки хром плохо относится к спецсимволам...

остался bootstrap, а вот туда я не могу затолкать то, что мне возвращает php... нашёл что-то похожее... осталось в "Modal Body" передать выхлоп date... Как?
подскажите пожалуйста! Вот исходники...

```js
function Show(id, res) {
  var msg = id + res;
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'json.php',
    data: msg,
    success: function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      if (data) {
        $('#myModal').modal('show')
      }
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <!-- Modal Header -->
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Heading</h4>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">?</button>
      </div>
      <!-- Modal body -->
      <div class="modal-body">
        Modal body..
      </div>
      <!-- Modal footer -->
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$("#myModal").find(".modal-body").html(data)` или что?

Comment: знаете, это очень похоже на то, что я искал... у меня невероятно мало опыта со скриптами... завтра проверю Ваше предложение, но уже вижу, что это должно сработать! спасибо Вам!

Comment: подразумевается, что там html код у вас в переменной. То есть разделять строки надо не через `\n` а через `<br/>`

Comment: нет, там не html, там обычный текст из массива после выборки sql... <br> тоже пробовал, но в хроме эффект тот-же - в алерте нельзя скопировать вывод... я так надеялся, что ничего не нужно будет изобретать... должен был быть элементарный дашборд без украшательств...

Comment: я не про алерт, а про вывод в данную модалку

Comment: уважаемый teran, скажите, как Вас можно поблагодарить в форуме? всё получилось, благодаря Вашему совету!

Comment: оформил ответом, можете ткнуть там галку )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Полученный в результате запроса Html код можно ставить в блок модалки с помощью следующего фрагмента кода.

```
$("#myModal").find(".modal-body").html(data);
```

Обратите внимание, что в `data` ожидается фрагмент html верстки, поэтому переносы строк следует выполнять через `<br/>` а не `\n`. Для быстрой замены `\n` на `br` в пхп есть соответствующая функция `nl2br()`